# My timer for JavaFX isn't working. Why?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to only start the time if the user clicks a button. Then I would call `timer.play()` once the button is clicked.

I can't understand why my timer isn't working. It prints

```
timer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        countTimerSecs++;
    }
)});
timer.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
```

This line of code is in a big function, so I only put that part of it.

```
timerTextField.setText(String.ValueOf(countTimerSecs));
```

The output stays at `0.0` and doesn't change

Comment: Where are you updating the text field?

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: But not in any way that answers my question.

Comment: I update the text field, when the user clicks the button, so once its clicked, I do timer.play() then set the timerField to it

Comment: Looks like the `TextField` call should be in the `Timer`.

Comment: Move the `setText` call into the `handle` method.

Comment: Exactly: you are not updating the text field when `countTimerSecs` changes.

Comment: I get javafx.animation.Timeline@41c60d14 @Michael and I tried to do toString() I still get the same thing

Comment: @markdevan That's because you were trying to put a `Timeline` instance into a text field. Put the `int` in there.

Answer (score 2):

```
timer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        timerTextField.setText(String.ValueOf(++countTimerSecs));
    }
)});
timer.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
```

Comment: Great! how can I make it in secs and minutes?

Comment: @markdevan Please don't add additional questions to your original question in comments. If you have additional questions, you should post a new question (but you should do an appropriate amount of research first - unlike you have done in this comment). In general, you should also take the [tour] and read the [help], in particular read how to create a [MCVE]. It will help you improve the quality of your questions.